# Why are CentOS mirrors HTTP and not HTTPS?

Tags: centos, security, https, http

As far as I know, HTTP is prone to [man-in-the-middle attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack). As such, the repositories in [Alpine Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux) or the [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) Mirrors are not HTTPS.

In the olden days, having HTTPS used to be an expensive matter. It cost server CPU time and the certificates weren't free. But it’s 2022 now, and we have plenty of ways to overcome those problems and security has been top priority than ever!

How can we obtain binaries smarter?

Also is this a problem in the wider Linux community? I.e., [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29), [Linux Mint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint), [openSUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSUSE), etc.?

Comment: See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18853/why-arent-application-downloads-routinely-done-over-https

Comment: Many CentOS mirrors are *both* HTTP and HTTPS (and all CentOS 9 Stream mirrors are both), so just pick an HTTPS one to use.

Comment: If the mirrors required credentials over HTTP and you comply and/or you are not verifying the checksum after downloading then you might not be the target audience for CentOS.

Comment: @Randall Since OP mentions Ubuntu as well, a lot of Ubuntu mirrors are unfortunately HTTP-only. I can't use them because my ISP runs (well-intended?) virus scans on all HTTP traffic and often blocks certain packages as false-positive.

Answer (score 38):

The packages are indeed signed, hence a manipulation would be noticed.

Also the packages are not *secret*, so there isn't any need to encrypt them on the *transfer*.

With the mass of downloads from mirrors, this probably saves them a lot of resources.

It is the same on [Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) and Ubuntu.

Comment: It is doubtful that "this probably saves them a lot of resources" https://istlsfastyet.com/

Comment: Plus for users in (and using the network of) a business, school or other organization that inspects network traffic, such inspection is transparent for HTTP, but HTTPS must be decrypted then re-encrypted with a different certificate which client software probably doesn't recognize, making system maintenance fail, which is typically bad.

Comment: Traffic analysis is a nice tool to discover what a server is installing, and thus what potentially vulnerable packages its pulling - so I disagree with your assertion that “the packages are not secret so no need to encrypt them”.

Comment: Thanks @Virsacer and all the editors of question and answers. One more clarification on the answer: Is it possible to manually check the package integrity? In my view the package and the Hashes can be changed through a man in the middle attack. Also, does the OS automatically check the signatures during installation?

Comment: @SydMK If a transmission is signed, and the attacker doesn't have a copy of the sender's private key, and you have a (untampered) copy of the sender's public key, then it is not possible for the attacker to sign a transmission they have changed through MiTM. Therefore you'd be able to detect such a change by using the sender's public key to see whether or not it was they who signed it.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh AES CPU time is not the only thing that increases resources. https being inherently anti MITM makes it impossible for http acceleration proxies to reduce the server load. HTTP accelerators like Squid.

Comment: @Moo is correct, the primary threat of information disclosure that HTTPS would protect against here is not that package xyz has some specific contents, it’s that a system at IP address 192.0.2.1 has downloaded package xyz (and therefore probably installed package xyz), which is _exceedingly_ useful information for someone attacking that system.

Comment: @moo I have read before that traffic analysis still allows you to know what is downloaded with https since you can observe the size of the download, and it's not secret. Maybe you can't differentiate packages by weight in every case, but you can make assumptions (if you installed 3 php modules, the next one is more likely another module than a Paint program if I doubt between those 2)

Comment: @Einacio traffic analysis of encrypted streams can and does still elicit usable info (see the analysis of encoded transmissions to and from spies during the cold war), but its still substantially harder to identify individual packages downloaded - with http, the info for an attacker is right there and they can move directly on to "oh, that web server is using package X which is vulnerable to exploit Y" with no further effort in analysis.  Security isnt about complete protection, its always about layers to make it more difficult for attackers.

Comment: Many Ubuntu mirrors reply on HTTPS now, for anyone that cares to type it in.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn, HTTPS doesn't hide the size of the transfer, and transfer size alone will tell you what packages were downloaded for all but the smallest files.

Comment: @trognanders That is not my experience. I had to specifically search Google for one that allows HTTPs because my ISP runs (well-intended?) virus scans on HTTP traffic and blocked some packages as false-positive.

Comment: @AndreKR The mirrors list for CentOS specifies which ones do HTTPS, so that should be pretty easy without Google. Also, off topic, but this is the mirror I always use when possible. It is hosted by a local university. https://mirror.arizona.edu/

Answer (score 22):

From a technical perspective the fact plain HTTP content can easily be cached by proxy servers can make quite a bit of difference when you need to manage and update more than a handful of systems.

Setting up local mirrors is often overkill and not practical, but when your proxy server can serve updates from a cache at LAN speeds, rather than every client in your network connecting to an online source...

Comment: I'd rather have a local mirror at 10Mb/s than a remote mirror at 9600bps.

Comment: Is something missing at the end? E.g., the implied *not overkill* is not that clear.

Comment: HTTP Caching is interesting. That definitely helps with edge-servers and fast downloads to the client machines. However don't you think at-least the keys should be securely transmitted? Otherwise manipulation in both ends (hard, but possible in my view) would cause malicious packages to be distributed. Don't you think?

Answer (score 15):

The packages are signed by an off-channel method ([GPG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Privacy_Guard) keys stored on your system).

The main use of having HTTP is to make it easy to have a dependency proxy between the Internet and your machines, which can save a lot of bandwidth and time by only having to download once (the first time) upgrades for potentially 1000s of (virtual) machines.

HTTPS prevents it (not completely, but makes it harder), because being end-to-end encrypted, you can't easily put something that'd intercept the downloaded packages to store them and serve them later.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of mirrors will reply on HTTPS if you change the URL, even if the link to them is only HTTP. Using this is better than not verifying anything at all, but puts absolute trust in the mirror host. Using the official GPG signatures to verify the downloads leaves the trust with only parties you already trust completely.

If you follow the instructions here, you only need to trust the certificate for `canonical.com`, for example. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

A system time error could cause issues with HTTPS. It is not a real issue, but it is sometimes unnecessary.

An out of date system that don't have trusted certificates is a pain to get them updated.

Mirrors that need to respond to the same [anycasted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anycast) hostname.

It takes time to set up distributed mirrors with valid certificates.

Answer (score 1):

CentOS distribution uses GPG to sign both rpm packages and [yum/dnf repository metadata](https://blog.centos.org/2018/07/improving-centos-package-delivery-security-with-signed-repository-metadata/), so that MITM attack will be prevented.

See also [How Fedora Secures Package Delivery](https://fedoramagazine.org/fedora-secures-package-delivery/), which is discussing Fedora, but package and repository metadata security tooling and policy is the same.